# Trying to get my ATI 6900 graphics cards DVI connected to two different monitors, one each

Tags: graphics-card, dvi, multiple-monitors

Recently I bought myself a ATI 6900 graphics card. I was hoping to attach two monitors to it using DVI connections, as I have two monitors now. My first monitor is connected and working well via a VGA cable and VGA-to-DVI connecter. It didn't work with my second monitor though, so I then brought myself a DVI-to-VGA lead hoping that this would solve the problem but yet I'm still in the same situation.

Previously I was running an LCD TV but via HDMI which worked perfectly fine with the other monitor. And now when I change my monitor to just going DVI, I can't view it and not even detect my second monitor..

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

Why am I stuck like this? I spent way too much for it to be faulty or something...

Comment: Just to be sure, you did install latest ATI driver right? Did you try using the cable that works with the first monitor with the second monitor just to prove that the second monitor is working?

Comment: Yeah, the second monitor works fine both DVI connections work fine as well

Comment: You recently bought yourself an ATI 6900 **SERIES** card.  It's not an ATI 6900.  It's something like a 6950, or a 6970, etc.  And what is the brand of the card?  I mean, who makes the actual card?  Not just the chipset.  I want to be able to look at this card.  And your reference to the LCD TV... was that with THIS card?  Were you using a monitor AND the TV at the same time?  Are you still doing that?  What kind of monitors are you using?  Do any of them actually have DVI connections?

Comment: Its an ATI Radeon 6950, I was using that LCD TV with this card, Yes, and Yes I was using that with my monitor at the same time, I'm currently still doing that, the monitor I'm using is the "Flatron E2360" And it does have a DVI connector. So does the monitor I wish to use in replacement of the LCD TV

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to detect the second monitor? Assuming you have Windows, right click on the desktop, go to screen resolution and then detect a second monitor.

Comment: Been through all that many times, and unfortunately.. Nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your monitor and see if it has a source button or something like that. It is possible that it's set to your VGA port instead of DVI. Also, do a manual detection on the screen resolution window - it may possibly pop up :)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The second monitor does have a Source button but after the "No signal" has passed it doesn't work as  if its just a dead monitor. Also when I've looked into "Screen resolution" it does say that my first moniter  is (analog) Although installing the digital side and removing the angalog drivers, it still seems to just go back to (analog) For some reason, I don't know if thats of any relivence or not? Still no detection of my second monitor :(

Answer (score 0):

> Yeah, the second monitor works fine both DVI connections work fine as well

The DVI input on your first monitor is broken.